# Yii2- data from two models in one GridView

Tags: gridview, view, model, yii2

I use yii2 and I have two tables with key:

First:

```
machine

machine_serial PK,name
```

Second:
**os**

```
id PK,os_name, machine_serial PFK
```

In relation 1: N

I generate model with CRUD for machine and OS
and I want to get data from two model in one view with GridView, where I have been using the primary key data

My Gridview:

```php
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel'  => $searchModel,
    'columns'      => [
        'os_name',
        'machine_serial',
        'machine.name',
        [
            'class'          => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width:50px;'],
            'header'         => 'Actions',
            'template'       => '{view}',
            'buttons'        => [
                //view button
                'view' => function ($url, $dataProvider) {
                    return Html::a('view',
                        ['view', 'id' => $dataProvider->id, 
                        'machine_serial' => $dataProvider->machine_serial],
                        ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);
                },
            ]
        ],
    ],
]);
```

but I get error:

> Getting unknown property: backend\models\Node::machine

I'm a beginner so please help :)

model os:

```php
namespace backend\models;
use Yii;

class Node extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'os';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id'], 'integer'],
            [['machine_serial'], 'string', 'max' => 8]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'machine_serial' => 'Machine Serial',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getMachineSerial()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Machine::className(), ['machine_serial' => 'machine_serial']);
    }

}
```

model machine:

```php
namespace backend\models;

use Yii;
use yii\db\Query;

class Machine extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'machine';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['machine_serial'], 'required'],
            [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 30]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'machine_serial' => 'Machine Serial',
            'name' => 'Name',
           ];
    }
    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getOs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Os::className(), ['machine_serial' => 'machine_serial']);
    }  
}
```

in os controller:

```php
 public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new NodeSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,

        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your model code?

Comment: And show `$dataProvider` code.

Answer (score 0):

In your GridView you have declared `'machine.name'`. But machine is not an attribute of your node model object. And in class Node you have the method `getMachineSerial()`.

I think that the method name is wrong. I guess it should be getMachine(). If you rename it I would assume that `'machine.name'` will work.

Or you could replace `'machine.name'` with `'machineSerial.name'` in the columns section of the GridView.